# Create list depending on heading 1 in word

Tags: microsoft-word

I need to create list depending on first heading. It looks similar to heading 2 - first number is heading 1, but second increments.

For example:

[image]

Appended numbers (green and red) are correct.

Any advice? :)

Comment: Is there a reason you couldn't use heading two? (I can't view the graphic.)

Comment: @Kelly: She seems to want to have two different “Heading 2” styles, that run independently and can be intermixed. So, for example, she might want to have an orange 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, …, and a blue 2.1, 2.2, 2.3, …, and be able to freely interleave the lists.

Comment: @Kristīne: It might help to tell us exactly what version of Word you are using. Also, what have you tried?

Comment: I'm using 2007 version. And I tried to _Define New List Styles_ and _New Multilevel Lists_ - different ways, but I assume I need to have only one Multilevel List, because if I have more - they are working independently. Or how I can connect them?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by defining a new multilevel list and associating it with your style, or with captions.

**Multilevel List**

1. Create a new style (using the **New Styles** button in the *Styles* window).
2. Bring up the *Multilevel List* window (by clicking the arrow next to the **Multilevel List** button in the *Paragraph* area of the *Home* tab).
3. Select **Define New Multilevel List.**
4. Click 2 (under *Click level to modify*:).
5. Click **More** if the *Link level to style* drop-down box isn't already displayed on the right.
6. Under *Link level to style*, select the name of your new style.
7. Make sure that the Heading 1 number is shown under *Enter formatting for number.* If not, select **Level 1** under *Include level number from:*.
8. Make sure that the *Restart list after* box is checked and that Level 1 is shown in the drop-down box.
9. Click **OK.**

**Captions**

If the items you need to number are all pictures, charts, or tables, you can adjust the settings for captions to number them based on heading 1.

1. From the *References* tab, select **Insert Caption.**
2. In the *Caption* dialog box, select **Numbering.**
3. Check the *Include chapter number* box and make sure that the *Chapter starts with style* drop-down box shows Heading 1.
4. Click **OK.**

If you have more types of captions than Word usually allows, you can create custom labels for them and have each type numbered separately.

Comment: All I still needed was to link first row to Heading 1 and everything is perfect! Thanks!

Comment: Ehh, all was good until I needed to add another title (heading 2), it's broken because in _Define New Multilevel List_ I linked heading 1 to first row, but if I don't - list is incrementing like in picture before :S

Comment: So, I noticed in your graphic, the items in the list are called pictures.  Would using a caption that's numbered based on heading 1 do what you want to do?

Comment: Item _Picture_ is just an example, I need more similar items as well, like _Chart_, _Table_ etc. And yes - if caption is based on heading 1 then that's what I want to achieve - it has heading 1 number and own incrementing number.

Comment: Updated the answer to include captions as an option and describe how to number the captions based on heading 1.

Comment: Yes, now it works exactly what I needed. I was digging in wrong place - I thought that I should create a new style and then associate heading 1 to it, bet that was wrong. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

You can apply numbering on your Heading styles:

On the “Home” tab, in the “Paragraph” panel, click on “Multilevel List” and select “Define New List Style…”

[image]

This will bring up a “Define New List Style” window.
Now click on “Format” and select “Numbering”:

[image]

This will bring up a “Modify Multilevel list” window.
You may need to click on the “More >>” button to get it to appear as shown below.

Now link the first level to the “Heading 1” style and the second level to the “Heading 2” style.
Set the formatting as desired (e.g., change alphabetic (a, b, c) numbering to Arabic (1, 2, 3) numbering as necessary, and specify that the second level number should include the first level number, delimited by a period), as shown below:

[image]

[image]

Now if you use the “Heading 1” style, it will number the paragraphs (headings) **1**, **2**, **3**, …, and if you apply the “Heading 2” style, it will number them as **1.1**, **1.2**, **1.3**, …

[image]

Comment: I believe that this isn’t an answer to the question. This seems to be a procedure to enable numbering on the “Heading 1” and “Heading 2” styles, which the OP already seems to have. The question asks how to create a new style that will combine the number of the current (i.e., most recent) “Heading 1” with an independent one-up counter.

Comment: Thanks for your diligence, @G-Man was correct - it's not exactly what I wanted. :)